# Grouping in WPF Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have an `ObservableCollection` of objects (Each object has a Name, Number, and Type property):

```
Name Number Type
a    1      1
a    1      2
b    2      1
c    4      3
c    4      5
```

What I'd like to display in the datagrid is something like this instead (grouping by type):

```
Name Number Types
a    1      1, 2
b    2      1
c    4      3, 5
```

A bit confused on how to achieve this with Model View.  One way is I could create a new object type, one that has a `List<int>` for Types, then iterate over the original collection and create a new collection that is bound instead to the `DataGrid`.  Just wondering if there's a more preferred/easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CollectionViewSource` that wraps your current data source.  This will allow you to add Groupings and Filters.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsTasks" Source="{StaticResource tasks}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="ProjectName"/>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Complete"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

See this link for complete examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126%28v=vs.110%29.aspx